# How to level up faster in MW3 survival mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I am at level 36 in Survival model, How do I level up faster? Should I keep playing higher waves or as [@agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/50145/19251) mentioned[this is my interpretation of what he said], restart after wave 15?

> Remember also that once you've hit round 15, everything from there on
>   out is just a matter of beating your previous (or your friends')
>   score. 15 is the highest round you need to hit for achievements, and
>   there's not really a XP/money benefit for playing to the very high
>   rounds anyhow.

Comment: I think what he is implying there is that the higher rounds are more difficult, but the xp/money stops scaling at 15. I could be wrong...I don't play MW3. Thus playing the lower levels produces easier/faster xp.

Comment: If you're playing for experience, you might also try running some of the "easy" Spec Ops missions, and see how much XP you gain per unit time on those versus the survival maps.  I haven't done the math, but it's worth trying, anyhow.  I feel like I cleared most of the missions prior to focusing on the survival mode, which helped unlock some of the more useful armory items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the lower levels, you're more likely to achieve bonuses like "killing spree" for killing a number of enemies without getting hit, or "rampage" for killing many enemies in quick succession.  The enemies also go down easier.

At the higher levels, you more than likely won't be getting as many bonus points, but the enemies are all worth more.  However, the levels become far more challenging and the waves take longer to clear.

I mention "round 15" because that's the minimum round you have to play to on *every* Spec Ops: Survival map in order to unlock an achievement.  There's nothing magic about this round otherwise.

If you're in this for experience gain or for the achievements, there's really little benefit in *forcing* yourself to play the higher levels, or being particularly disappointed if you fail.  It can be good practice or a fun challenge, but I wouldn't feel pressure to survive every round unless you're trying to beat your (or your friends') high scores.

Comment: I am trying to level up so I can get perk "Sleight of Hand", I believe this will make life easier at higher waves, Any thoughts?

Comment: @iraSenthil: if your trying to level up as fast as possible the best advice I could give you is to simply keep going. Surviving to higher waves will grant more exp per kill, and if your good at it then your gonna mow down more enemies and get more experience. You could also try Agent86's idea of trying out some of the spec ops and maybe finding one that grants a lot of exp. Other than that its just a grind, no real way around it.

Comment: @iraSenthil, Sleight of Hand is useful, as is carrying 2 primary weapons.  However, by the time you get all the way to level 50 you'll probably be quite a pro at the game anyhow :)

Answer (score 0):

This only works on single player because on multi-player you can only buy one turret, but you can buy 2 turrets and place them in the room atop of the stairs on bootleg. Make the grenade turret facing the door coming from the stairs, and make the normal turret face the door coming from outside, then stand behind the crates, and you should be able to go AFK even and still level up.

Answer (score 0):

Another good place to camp is the kitchen in resistance. What you do is save up as much cash before wave 5 and then buy a LMG with grip and go under the bridge/ walk way in the bottom right corner of the map and proceed to kill the enemy helios. On wave 6 proceed to go into the kitchen area (it is the building in which the floor is collapsed and partly on fire in the centre of the map), moving from your spawn position at the beginning of the survival mode.

Go in the door up the ramp left through the doorway and you will see the kitchen in front of a doorway, and to the right of a table prone on the floor in there and enemies will run through from the way you came in and also the other door. Just sit there and pick them off as they go through. After that once you have completed the first juggs wave purchase a turret and place it behind the table next to the kitchen. Once you have enough money again purchase a second turret. Either will work and point both towards the doorway in the middle of the room. This method will easily work and you can get right up to high levels fast.

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot easier to try to get multiple things at once. For example, I once got 2000 experience for doing all of the following:

- Killstreak (kill 5 or more people in a row within at least half a second second1 of the other kills)
- Butcher (like Killstreak , but with stabbing)
- Multikill (kill 5 or more as the round starts)
- another killstreak.

It's kinda hard to do it with high rounds, but I did it at 23. That brought me up a level.